# How can I install pc, a pascal compiler?

Tags: pascal

I only found fpc but not pc in my system to compile pascal. The system is redhat. How should I install pc? The only one I found is http://www.freepascal.org/. But it doesn't seem have pc.

Comment: It's there in the list of supported platforms.  If you are running RedHat, you need to know which distro you have.  Follow the instructions for that.

Comment: Is this a riddle?

Answer (score 5):

pc is a general name for the system Pascal compiler on old unices, just like cc was the equivalent for the system C compiler.

If the code is really old and from mainframe or unix descent (early eighties), it is probably Berkeley, Sun or some other OS/vendor specific Pascal. If not then sb just tried to mimic that for the buildsystem of  a newer codebase by symlinking "pc" to some other compiler.

Anyway, "pc" is too generic, and more information is needed to know what compiler you are searching for. Free Pascal always referred to itself either as ppc or as fpc, never as "pc".

To my best knowledge Berkeley Pascal was removed from the distro going from BSD to *BSD in the early nineties, and never made it to Linux.

Your best bet is to port to an existing compiler, porting to Free Pascal (using mode ISO) or Gnu Pascal in the very unlikely case that it is an Extended Pascal dialect codebase.  Gnu Pascal, despite being unmaintained, is still buildable with a considerable effort.

The convention to symlink pascal compilers to "pc" never really caught on, and neither is there an universal buildsystem that requires the shortcut.

Even for C buildsystems seems to favour the CC environment variable for the C compiler's name nowadays.